# finding string in a list and return it index or -1

Tags: python, list, indexing

Defining a procedure which return an index of item or -1 if the item not in list

```
def ser(a,b):
    for j in a:
        if j == b:
            return (a.index(b))
        else:
            return -1

print (ser([1,2,3],3))
```

It's always return me -1. If i cut the 'else' part, it works. So why ?

Comment: Think about it, what happens if the first element of `a` doesn't equal `b`.

Comment: Your function returns -1 after first unsuccessful search.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the first time you do not match the condition in your loop you immediately return and leave your method. You need to re-think your logic here to determine what it is you want to do when you don't match. Ultimately, you want to continue looping until you have exhausted your checks.

So, simply set your `return -1` outside of your loop. If you go through your entire loop, you have not found your match, so you can then return -1

```
def ser(a,b):
    for j in a:
        if j == b:
            return (a.index(b))
    return -1

print (ser([1,2,3],3))
```

Alternatively, the loop can be avoided by using [in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in). So, you can actually re-write your method to this:

```
def ser(a, b):
    if b in a:
        return a.index(b)
    return -1
```

You are checking to see if item `b` is in list `a`, if it is, return the index, otherwise return -1

To take the simplification further, you can actually set this in to a single line in your `return`:

```
def ser(a, b):
    return a.index(b) if b in a else -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `else` block is executed after the first iteration does not fulfill `j == b`.

You're better off moving the else block to the `for` which executes if the item is not found after the `for` loop is *exhausted*:

```
def ser(a,b):
    for j in a:
        if j == b:
            return (a.index(b))
    else: # or put default return on this line
         return -1
```

More importantly, You could also check for containment using `b in a` without needing to iterate through the list.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the for loop, it will test if the first element in the array is equal to b. It is not, so the code returns -1 immediately, without testing the other elements of the array.

For your case, the correct code is:

```
def ser(a,b):
    for j in a:
        if j == b:
            return (a.index(b))
    return -1
```

In this way, the code will try all elements in the array, and will return -1 if none of them is equal to b.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to do anything fancy, simple one-liner will work:

```
def ser(a,b):
    return a.index(b) if b in a else -1

# Example
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ser(my_list, 2)
# returns: 1

ser(my_list, 8)
# returns: -1
```